# How to add gravity forms CLI support in WP-CLI?

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms, wp-cli

I am trying to access gravity forms 'gf' commands with WP-CLI in terminal. so I want execute this command

```
wp gf check-update
```

I am getting:

'gf' is not a registered wp command. See 'wp help' for available commands.

I am trying to help myself from their [docs](https://docs.gravityforms.com). Nothing helpful found.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the Gravity Forms CLI plugin installed and be in the command line directory of your WordPress site for many of its commands to work correctly. This means you must be in the same directory as your site's wp-config.php file

Comment: I did not know about Gravity Forms CLI Add-On plugin. thanks.